# How do I create a path to create followers in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using acts_as_followers and want to know have a path that I can pass to a link_to :remote => true link so that a User can follower various different entities.

Here is what I have in the routes (via rake routes)

> follow
>   /users/follow/:followed_type/:followed_id(.:format)
>   {:controller=>"users",
>   :action=>"follow_this"}

This is what is in routes.rb:

```
match 'users/follow/:followed_type/:followed_id' => 'users#follow_this', :as => "follow"
```

But I'm not clear how I pass the values into the URL string using the path helper?  I need to pass in the type as a string (e.g. "Vendor"), and the :id...but how do I do that?

This was i can enable a user to press the link and it will call this action and create the following relationship.

```
46   def follows_this
 47 
 48     followed_type = params[:followed_type]
 49     followed_class = class_type.camelize.constantize
 50     followed = followed_class.find(params[:followed_id])
 51     current_user.follow(followed)  #uses acts_as_follower plugin
 52 
 53   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
put '/users/follow/:followed_type/:followed_id' => 'users#follow_this', :as => "follow"
```

usage

```
<%= link_to "Follow White Rabbit", follow_path(:followed_type => "some type", :followed_id => "some_id"), :method => :put %>
```

`match` means you can call ANY of requests: GET, POST, PUT or DELETE. So it better to specify wich one you want to use. As far as you updating some data - use `PUT`, if you are creating some data - `POST`, if you are deleting - `DELETE` and if you just fetch - `GET`

Comment: I used 'match'...hmmm...what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @floor -- I got an error :( No route matches {:follow_type=>"Vendor", :follow_id=>1, :action=>"follow_this", :controller=>"users"}

Comment: Actually `put` will be better. `match` means you can call ANY of requests: GET, POST, PUT or DELETE. So it better to specify wich one you want to use. As far as you updating some data - use `PUT`, if you are creating some data - `POST`, if you are deleting - `DELETE` and if you just fetch - `GET`

Comment: show your controller. It means it can't find your `follow_this` action